# Как сохранять данные (любые типы, но главное String из TextField) используя Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Добрый день комьюнити! Неизбежно приближается то день, когда мне надо будет научиться сохранять данные (любые) на определенное время с помощью языка Swift. Не могли бы Вы подсказать мне как (главное String из TextField!) , или же направить мои поиски в правильном направлении...
Я так понимаю что надо поднимать БД и с помощью определенных методов обрабатывать ее...
Через UserDefaults.standard я могу сохранить только один "набор" чего, конечно же, не достаточно...

Comment: что именно надо сохранить? почему userDefaults не подходит?

Comment: Я сохраняю туда три String, но почему-то когда я записываю " новый комплект" из трех String, первые 3 строчки заменяются на новые три. Может я что-то делаю не правильно? Могу привести пример своего кода если надо. К Тому же после рестарта OS X данные так же теряются...

Comment: Что значит один набор? Набор чего? Вы в начале говорите, что хотите сохранить строку.

Comment: Да я хочу сохранить строку и я ее сохраняю (она сохраняется даже после рестарта XCOD), но она перезаписывается другой строкой, если я пытаюсь сохранить вторую. При этом последняя записанная строка теряется после рестарта OS X.

Comment: Хотелось бы записать их на долго (пока не решу их удалить) с возможностью до записывать новые строки.

Comment: я записываю туда 3 разные строки с 3 разными ключами. Я так понимаю сохраняются они в дикшанери.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы используете `UserDefaults` Вы можете сохранить туда одно значение для одного ключа. Можно пойти на хитрость и сделать массив строк и сохранять его в `UserDefaults`. Но я бы посоветовал пользоваться `Core Data` для хранения различных данных. Но все зависит от Ваших целей.